# как вывести значение ключа из массива если в одном из индексов массива этого ключа нету

Tags: swift4

Всем доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста как вывести значение "foods1", "foods2" ключа "favFoods" из массива если в одном из индексов массива этого ключа нету

Вот мой Json

```
     {
 "pets": [
{
  "name" : "Purrsloud",
  "species" : "Cat",
  "favFoods" : "foods1",
  "birthYear" : 2016,
  "photo" : "https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/images/cat-2.jpg"
},
{
  "name" : "Barksalot",
  "species" : "Dog",
  "birthYear" : 2008,
  "photo" : "https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/images/dog-1.jpg"
},
{
  "name" : "Meowsalot",
  "species" : "Cat",
  "favFoods" : "foods2",
  "birthYear" : 2012,
  "photo" : "https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/images/cat-1.jpg"
}
]
}
```

Вот мой код

```
   if a1.pets != nil {

    cell.l3.text = self.a1.pets![indexPath.row].favFoods

    }
```

Вот ошибка которую выбивает:
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Как парсите json?

Comment: Спасибо уже разобрался. Очень приятно что откликнулись :)